# How to add a tags file with expand

Tags: tags

I'm trying to add a plugin that will provide additional tags files to look up the documentation of a language: https://github.com/DanielSiepmann/phpstorm-stubs/blob/feature/add-dynamic-tags-file/plugin/php.vim
But none of my tries worked out:

```
let &l:tags += expand('%:p:h:h') . "/tags"
let &tags = expand('%:p:h:h') . "/tags"
set tags += expand('%:p:h:h') . "/tags"
```

The first solution returns the following error:

> Error detected while processing
>   /Users/siepmann/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle/phpstorm-stubs/plugin/php.vim:
>   line    1: E734: Wrong variable type for += Press ENTER or type
>   command to continue

The second one will prevent all other defaults that would be set in addition. So `tags=./tags,tags` will become `tags=~/Projects/typo3/tags` where `~/Projects/typo3/` is current working dir.

The thing is that the plugin should ship with the tags file and as the plugin can be installed into multiple locations the include should be dynamic.

So what will be a working solution / approach?

Comment: According to http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:let the let &l: version will work like setlocal. That was a try inside ftplugin/php.vim to only adjust tags for php files.

& is to handle settings as variables according to the documentation to let expand work while adjusting the setting.

What's the issue with absolut path?

Comment: Concatenation charachter for strings in vim is `.`, so you should use `.=` to add to a string value.

Comment: Thanks @dNitro, that's one issue. The other is that expand works on working directory not on the file it resists. So how can I provide the path relative to plugin?

And why is `._` the right way even if `tags` is a list of values. In my opinion http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:set+= should apply.

Comment: When using `set`, don't use spaces, i.e. use `set tags+=<path>`. Also, if you want to get a path relative to the script file it's run from, try something like `let parent_dir = resolve(expand('<sfile>:p:h'))` for example, and use that.

Comment: Thanks @VanLaser I didn't see the `<sfile>` in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @dNitro and @VanLaser the following is the working solution.

In `ftplugin/php.vim`:

```
if &l:tags == ""
    " Gather information
    let s:additionalFile=expand('<sfile>:p:h:h')."/tags"
    let s:existingPath=&tags
    let s:newPath=s:existingPath.",".s:additionalFile

    if s:existingPath[-1:] == ""
        let s:newPath=s:additionalFile
    endif

    " Set new path
    let &l:tags=s:newPath
endif
```

This will first check if tags is set for current buffer. If not it will fetch the path relative to tags file in the current plugin.
Next it will concatenate the global `tags` setting with the new file if global `tags` contains something. This is due to the fact that `let &l:tags+=s:newPath` will not work.